# custom constraint with complex logic or alternative

Tags: search, marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there any way to create a custom constraint where the right part can include complex logic? i.e.

```
name:(phil OR tom)
```

In my function, when I get the $right side, the whole value has been reduced to a simple concatenated string of all of the text, i.e.

```
<cts:word-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:text>phil tom</cts:text>
</cts:word-query>
```

What I am looking to do is to take a parsed query and then add my own additions to the parsed query. So I was hoping that there was some way to get the $right parameter to be something like

```
<cts:or-query xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text>phil</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
  <cts:word-query>
    <cts:text>tom</cts:text>
  </cts:word-query>
</cts:or-query>
```

I want to take the output results of the query and expand with another query to get the real results. i.e. I have a `name` constraint which restricts search to various name fields.  After finding the matching people, I want to turn the results into a hierarchy of people from the matching people, maybe 2 levels down.  This does not seem to make sense as a transform result or a custom constraint. Would this just be a custom REST endpoint?  I was hoping to make use of the paging already built into the standard search endpoint.

Answer (score 5):

A few thoughts come to mind.At present you best write that as:

```
name:phil OR name:tom
```

Apart from that, the [cts:parse](http://docs.marklogic.com/cts:parse) function provides more complex support, than the [search:parse](http://docs.marklogic.com/search:parse) with which the REST api is running now.

When using custom constraints, and you have control over how it is being sent to the REST api, consider sending it as a [custom-constraint-query](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query#id_28778) in a [structuredQuery](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/structured-query). That allows you sending it unparsed, and doing parsing inside your constraint.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up creating a custom resource REST endpoint, and that allowed me to do what I needed to do.